Adding tick lines and labels to the x and y axis of a D3 chart in React Native
I've modified the chart from this tutorial.
I'm looking to add tick lines and labels to the x and y axis. Can anybody please provide some suggestions?
app.tsx
import React from 'react';
import {Dimensions, StyleSheet, SafeAreaView} from 'react-native';

import Animated from 'react-native-reanimated';
import LineChart from './LineChart';

const {width} = Dimensions.get('screen');

const CARD_WIDTH = width - 20;
const GRAPH_WIDTH = CARD_WIDTH - 60;
const CARD_HEIGHT = 325;
const GRAPH_HEIGHT = 200;

export type GraphData = {
  max: number;
  min: number;
  curve: string;
};

const graphData: GraphData[] = [];

const App = () => {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <Animated.View style={styles.graphCard}>
        <LineChart
          height={GRAPH_HEIGHT}
          width={GRAPH_WIDTH}
          data={graphData}
          bottomPadding={20}
          leftPadding={0}
        />
      </Animated.View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    marginTop: 20,
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  graphCard: {
    elevation: 5,
    borderRadius: 20,
    height: CARD_HEIGHT,
    width: CARD_WIDTH,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    shadowColor: '#000',
    shadowOffset: {
      width: 0,
      height: 2,
    },
    shadowOpacity: 0.25,
    shadowRadius: 3.84,
  },
});

export default App;

linechart.tsx
import React, {FC} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, SafeAreaView, View, Text} from 'react-native';

import Animated from 'react-native-reanimated';

import {GraphData} from './App';
import ButtonSection from './ButtonSection';

type LineChartProps = {
  height: number;
  width: number;
  data: GraphData[];
  leftPadding: number;
  bottomPadding: number;
};

const LineChart: FC<LineChartProps> = () => {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.titleContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.titleText}>FACEBOOK</Text>
        <Text style={styles.titleText}>0</Text>
      </View>
      <Animated.View style={styles.chartContainer}></Animated.View>
      <ButtonSection
        q1Tapped={() => {}}
        q2Tapped={() => {}}
        q3Tapped={() => {}}
        q4Tapped={() => {}}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  chartContainer: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  titleContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    marginVertical: 12,
    marginHorizontal: 30,
  },
  titleText: {
    fontSize: 20,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    marginTop: 10,
    color: 'black',
  },
  priceText: {
    fontSize: 20,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
});

export default LineChart;

I've tried svg.append but I can't get it to work
